# Is it possible to run eclipse IDE on a network so other users can work with you? Like google docs?

Tags: android, eclipse, networking, share, sharing

Would that be possible or is that just fantasy? I am partnered with my friend to work on a project and im not sure if it is possible to work on code like that, if it is possible is there any tutorial as to how to set this up?

Comment: +1 Good idea. I am also wondering if there is one. Now I am using the SVN for teamwork.

Comment: could you explain what SVN is? could be a big help as my friend and I live a good bit away from eachother so I would think this would be a fantastic idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system to do what you want, some example of version control system are GIT, SVN, Mercurial, CVS ...

Comment: oh cool thanks, also after doing some more googling, i have found some information suggesting that eclipse is working on a new online ide, which im assuming will incorporate the same idea... here is the link if anyone is interested

http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/who-needs-online-ide

Answer (score 1):

A version control system is a good help, and you should look into that.

For real-time collaborative editing in Eclipse you could try [the DocShare-plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin).

Comment: thats exactly what we need, but how do i download it? it sends me from page to page to page

Comment: It's part of the Eclipse Communication Framework, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/downloads.php). Setting it up seems to require some work, so you might be better off just using a version control system like SVN or Git and just sort sort out conflicts with that @makar.